# Echo PID of child process to a file when starting - bash

Tags: bash

I'm wondering if there is a way to start a child process (not as a background process), and get its PID, possibly outputting it to a file.

I am starting a process in a bash script, namely java, and I'd like to be able to output the PID of this java process to a file, so I can use it in other scripts. The problem is that I'm not starting java as a background process, so I can't use `$!`. Any ideas onto how I would output the PID of the `java` process that I just started to a file?

Note that this java process is not going to be the only java process running on the system - if I get this working I'll be outputting the child process for different java processes to different files.

Only thing I've thought of is possible starting a background process that knows the PID of the current bash script, before starting java. Then using that background process to find the child process from the bash script. I wouldn't know exactly how to implement this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably to get the application itself to do it. 
If that’s not an option, try wrapping the app in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo My pid is $$.
exec /the/real/path/to/the/app
```

The key is the `exec` command, which causes the shell (the process that’s handling the script) to run that last program *without forking*, so it (the application) takes over process and inherits its PID.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution for my problem, thanks!